# Linking Urls in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I recently started learning as a way of setting foot in python programming. I've been facing problems with URLs since I'm a beginner. So I've been doing this signature verification web app. I'm not facing major problems except when it comes to URL patterns. When I enter the localhost address and the port and execute the program, it displays this error displayed [here](https://ibb.co/g6pLp7q). I've gone to the URL files on Django and I see no [errors](https://ibb.co/zxjzTq8) on the code that I've written and [also](https://ibb.co/Lvnj7r4) on the main folders URL. Can someone help me find the problem or what I'm doing wrong by checking the images and telling me? Thank you to all the people who checked this out.

Comment: Try navigating to http://localhost:8000/Main

From what I can tell, the problem is in your main project URLs, you don't have a path to ' '. You have a path to Main and Main has a path to ' '. You may also need to add a / after Main in the urls file. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change

```
path('Main', include('Main.urls'))
```

to

```
path('', include('Main.urls'))
```

What you did is the `Main.urls` will always be prefixed by `Main` ex: [localhost:8000/Main](http://localhost:8000/Main)

Comment: @Spirit Great, accept the answer if ti solve your issue